# How do I capture multiple lines with regexp?

Tags: c++, c, regex, c++11

This is my input string:

```
string MyS = "program{anything}";
```

I want to match everything within parenthesis so I used this regex:

```
regex MyR("program{(.*)}");
```

matches was (what i need) =

```
program{anything}
anything
```

it is true but when i change my string to

```
string Mys = "program{
anything line1
anything line2
}";
```

with this regex I don't get what I hope for:

```
anything line1
anything line2
```

That is, I want to capture everything in all lines.

What regex should I use to get all of the things in `{}` in one matches element?

Comment: **i just want to use regex ...** then why'd tag `C`, `C++`?

Comment: I englishified it while trying to extract the OP's intention. If my translation is fair, than the question makes less sense than before. If my translation is poor, I've made the question less comprehensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, add `?` after your quantifier `*`, or it may also match items between two results. `{anything} bla bla bla {somethingelse}` might match `anything} bla bla bla {somethingelse` Alternatively, use `[^}]` instead of your wildcard `.`

Speaking of witch, the wildcard `.` **does not** contain newlines. Use `[^}]` instead, to also include newlines.

`program{([^}]*?)}` should do nicely.

Comment: `((?:.|\n)*?)` is bad and inefficient. Use `[\s\S]`. Here, I think all is needed is a negated class `[^}]`.

Comment: @stribizhev You're right, was stuck on that to show "include newlines" idea.